# Unlock file generated from Bitmap object

Tags: c#, file, bitmap, gdi+

I have this method to get a thumbnail from an image on disk:

```
public static BitmapImage GetThumbnail()
{
    var dlg = new OpenFileDialog {Filter = "Imágenes|" + extensionesImagenes};
    var result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        var tempFolder = Path.GetTempPath() + "MyTempFolder\\";

        if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);

        using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(170, 170))
        {
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(new Bitmap(dlg.FileName), new Rectangle(0, 0, 170, 170));
            }

            thumbnail.Save(tempFolder + "foto.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(tempFolder + "foto.jpg"));
    }

    return null;
}
```

If I run it for the first time there's no problem. But when I run it for the second time I get "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception because the file is being used by my app.

The method could be invoked several times depending of the actions made by users and the file should be overwritten. As a matter of fact, if the file exist when I invoke the method for the first time it's successfully overwritten.

The file is generated by the Save() method of the Bitmap class and I'm not using any stream.

How can I unlock the file?

TIA

**EDIT**

I'm not using MemoryStream because I need the file in another method: when an user invokes the GetThumbnail method the thumbnail will be shown in a StackPanel (the thumbnail is the ImageSource of the StackPanel.)

Later the user could save to database the info shown in a WPF form, image included, and the method that saves to database need to read the bytes from the saved image.

**EDIT 2**

Before using thumbnails I was using this method:

```
public static BitmapImage GetImage()
{
    var dlg = new OpenFileDialog {Filter = "Imágenes|" + extensionesImagenes};
    var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    return result == true ? new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName)) : null;
}
```

It was working ok.

Now that I'm using thumbnails the problem with a MemoryStream is that I can't set the Uri for the image.

For example I was using:

```
imagenNueva = InterfazUtil.GetImage(); // GetImage() is now GetThumbnail()
var rutaFoto = (imagenNueva != null) ? imagenNueva.ToString() : null;
```

The string rutaFoto was passed to the method that save the info to the database and it uses this variable to read the image from disk.

In the GetThumbnail method I did convert the Image thumbnail to a BitmapImage and I did try to set the SourceUri and BaseUri with:

new Uri(dialog.FileName);

But when I invoke imagenNueva.ToString() I don't get a valid Uri.

Comment: when is result ever true? You never close your dialog so I don't know if that has anything to do with it (I doubt it) (`using(var dlg...`). I think its more that `.Save` cant overwrite existing files maybe

Comment: Thanks. The dialog is closed and the result == true condition is really evaluated when the user closes the dialog.

Comment: The dialog is closed yes, but its not disposed

Comment: The dialog does't implement IDisposable. If i try to use it in a using statement I get an error.

Comment: Ah apologies, I thought all dialogs opened with showdialog need disposing.. **Edit** I notice you still have a bitmap that isn't disposed when you draw your image. If you step through your method, what line do you get the erorr on

Comment: The line is: thumbnail.Save(tempFolder + ...

Comment: My last guess would be to return a `Clone` then, (`BitmapImage().Clone()`)

Comment: Did it and still get the error. But it was a nice try. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 gr.DrawImage(new Bitmap(dlg.FileName), new Rectangle(0, 0, 170, 170));
```

Using a bitmap like that is very troublesome.  It locks the "dlg.FileName" file and it will take a while before the garbage collector releases it.  You'll need to write it like this instead:

```
 using (var bmp = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName)) {
     gr.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 170, 170));
 }
```

Now it gets disposed immediately after use and that releases the lock on the file as well.

Btw, you can completely avoid writing code like this if you use a MemoryStream instead.  Just save the image to the MemoryStream so you don't need a file.  Assuming the images are not that big or you can count on running on a 64-bit operating system.  Not otherwise a reason to avoid disposing bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks. I did replace the line with the using version but I'm still getting the same error at the same line. I´m not using MemoryStream because the file is needed in other place. I will edit OP to explain it.

Comment: Well, maybe it isn't the only place where you forgot to dispose an image.  You as much said so in this comment.

Comment: I wrote a second edit. I hope it clarifies a bit what I'm doing.

Comment: Hans, I wrote the second edit very quickly and it was a bit unclear. I did modify it and now (I hope) it's more clear. If you read it maybe you can give me a hint to work around my problem using a MemoryStream. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A "bit unclear" is an understatement.  I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: I guess. English is not my natural language. Sorry for make you waste your time. :(